# Visual Studio- PDB File go to temp folder

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, pdb-files

I try to debug my product with a PDB file.
When the process is running, I am attaching the visual studio to the process, and then I am trying to load the relevant PDB File.

When I Right click on the DLL, and Load Symbols, i expect to get a File dialog to chose my PDB file, but for some reason, the visual studio found the PDB file in temp folder:

C:\Users..\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache...

I tried to delete this folder, to remove all the folders from the symbols settings, but for some reason, it still detect the DLL on the temp folder.
Even if i try to load a different DLL, it create new folder inside the symbol cache, and it think that the PDB file is existing over there.

Offcurse that i am not able to put breakpoint because it dosent find the real PDB file...

Anyone have any idea how i change it so i will get the File Dialog to chose the right PDB file?

note: I am using Visual studio 2013.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You'll have to document the content of Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols.  If you see more than one entry in the "Symbol file (.pdb) locations" listbox then you're much better off talking to an experienced team member instead of strangers on the Internet.

Comment: I took all of them off, i only have "Microsoft Symbol Servers" and it's not checked. for some reason, it still go automatically to temp folder